# Один токен на два сайта Laravel

Tags: laravel, token

Всем привет. Есть вопрос. Можно ли настроить два сайта на laravel, чтобы между ними ходить по одному токену? И юзеру не приходилось заново логиниться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически можно, если использовать одну БД (хотя бы таблицу `users`), одинаковый `APP_KEY` в `.env` файле и хранилищем сессий сделать БД (`SESSION_DRIVER=database`). (Делать так не надо на рабочих проектах)

Практически - это гемор.

Но то, что ты имеешь ввиду, называется **SSO** ([Single-Sign-On](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)).